# Manipular uma imagem antes de adiciona-la em um elemento canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Estou adicionando uma imagem dinamicamente em um `canvas`, porem não estou conseguindo redimensiona-la corretamente.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIaBN.jpg";

function inserir() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('meuCanvas');
  var heightCanvas = 498;
  var widthCanvas = 598;
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  context.fillStyle = '#fff';
  context.clearRect(1, 1, widthCanvas, heightCanvas);

  var tamanho = document.getElementById('tamanho').value;
  var orientacao = document.getElementById('orientacao').value;

  img.height = tamanho;

  rotacionarImagem(orientacao);

  pintar(context);
}


function pintar(context) {
  context.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}

function rotacionarImagem(orientacao) {
  switch (orientacao) {
    case "N":
      img.style.Transform = "rotate(0deg)"
      img.style.MozTransform = "rotate(0deg)"
      img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(0deg)"
      break;
    case "L":
      img.style.Transform = "rotate(90deg)"
      img.style.MozTransform = "rotate(90deg)"
      img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(90deg)"
      break;
    case "S":
      img.style.Transform = "rotate(180deg)"
      img.style.MozTransform = "rotate(180deg)"
      img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(180deg)"
      break;
    case "O":
      img.style.Transform = "rotate(270deg)"
      img.style.MozTransform = "rotate(270deg)"
      img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(270deg)"
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
Virar para:
<select id="orientacao">
  <option value="N">Norte</option>
  <option value="S">Sul</option>
  <option value="L">Leste</option>
  <option value="O">Oeste</option>
</select>
Tamanho (em pixel):
<input id="tamanho" type="text">
<input class="" value="Inserir" onclick="inserir();" type="button">
<canvas id="meuCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
```

Na verdade eu preciso redimensiona-la, rotaciona-la e coloca-la em um local especifico do `canvas`.

Sei que a função `drawImage` tem mais argumentos, porém esta difícil trabalhar com eles, principalmente no sentido de rotacionar a imagem...

`context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height`);

> **img** - Especifica a imagem para usar.
>
> **sx** (opcional) - A coordenada x onde começa um recorte da imagem.
>
> **sy** (opcional) - A coordenada y onde começa um recorte da imagem.
>
> **swidth** (opcional) - A largura da imagem cortada.
>
> **sheight** (opcional) - A altura da imagem cortada.
>
> **x** A coordenada x onde colocar a imagem na tela.
>
> **y** A coordenada y onde colocar a imagem na tela.
>
> **width** (opcional) - A largura da imagem a ser usada (trecho ou redução da imagem)
>
> **height** (opcional) - A altura da imagem a ser usada (trecho ou redução da imagem)

Pensei que fosse mais fácil criar uma imagem com o atributo `hidden` a parte no meu formulário e depois de manipula-la adicionar no canvas, porém desse modo a imagem é desenhada da forma inicial, de antes de começar a manipula-la...

---

### Edit

Utilizando uma função encontrada no SO em inglês eu só não consigo adaptar para posicionar no local correto:

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIaBN.jpg";
var orientacao, tamanho, x, y;

function inserir() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('meuCanvas');
  var heightCanvas = 498;
  var widthCanvas = 598;

  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  context.fillStyle = '#fff';
  context.clearRect(1, 1, widthCanvas, heightCanvas);

  tamanho = document.getElementById('tamanho').value;
  orientacao = document.getElementById('orientacao').value;
  x = document.getElementById('x').value;
  y = document.getElementById('y').value;

  context.save();
  rotacionarImagem(canvas, context);
  pintar(context, tamanho);
  context.restore();
}


function pintar(context, tamanho) {
  context.drawImage(img, -x / 2, -y / 2, tamanho, tamanho);
}

function rotacionarImagem(canvas, context) {
  switch (orientacao) {
    case "N":
      angulo = 0;
      break;
    case "L":
      angulo = 90;
      break;
    case "S":
      angulo = 180;
      break;
    case "O":
      angulo = 270;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  context.rotate(angulo * Math.PI / 180);
}
```

```html
Virar para:
<select id="orientacao">
  <option value="N">Norte</option>
  <option value="S">Sul</option>
  <option value="L">Leste</option>
  <option value="O">Oeste</option>
</select>
Tamanho (em pixel):
<input id="tamanho" type="text">Posição (x,y):
<input id="x" type="text">
<input id="y" type="text">
<input class="" value="Inserir" onclick="inserir();" type="button">
<canvas id="meuCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
```

Desse modo a imagem só rotaciona sobre o próprio eixo se o `tamanho` da imagem for o mesmo valor de `x` e `y`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O canvas não reconhece propriedades HTML, por isso não adianta modificar os estilos do elemento da imagem.

Para rotacionar a imagem pelo seu próprio eixo basta declarar as posições centrais da mesma no método `.translate(...)`, depois desenhar ela no canvas com a posição da metade do tamanho de sí mesma. Tente:

```
// cria o ângulo da imagem
var angulo = orientacao === 'N' ? 0   :
             orientacao === 'L' ? 90  :
             orientacao === 'S' ? 180 :
                                  270; // O

// transforma o canvas com as posições centrais da imagem
context.translate(x + (tamanho / 2), y + (tamanho / 2));

// rotaciona
context.rotate((angulo * Math.PI) / 180);

// desenha a imagem na metade do seu tamanho negativo
context.drawImage(img, -tamanho / 2, -tamanho / 2, tamanho, tamanho);

// desfaz a rotação
context.rotate((-angulo * Math.PI) / 180);

// destransforma
context.translate(-x - (tamanho / 2), -y - (tamanho / 2));
```

Baseado em uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37622176#answer-37622538) de uma de minhas perguntas.